# Render object in front of camera in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, transformation

I wanna have an object (e.g. a sphere) which is placed directly in front of the camera (let's say "5cm" in front). When the camera is moved, the object should always follow the movement of the camera.

In my rendering loop, I calculate the position of the camera in world space using the inverse of the view matrix:

```
glm::mat4 viewMatrixInverse = glm::inverse(camera->GetViewMatrix());
glm::vec3 cameraPositionWorldSpace = glm::vec3(viewMatrixInverse[3][0], viewMatrixInverse[3][1], viewMatrixInverse[3][2]);
```

This seems to work fine and as I move towards the world origin, the camera position approaches (0,0,0) as well. Now when I try to render a sphere at the camera position, this works perfectly fine and the camera is always positioned in the centre of the sphere.

The rendering part looks like this:

```
sphere->ResetModelMatrix();
sphere->TranslateModel(cameraPositionWorldSpace);
sphere->Render(GL_TRIANGLES);
```

Now, I don't want to "sit" inside the sphere, I'd rather have the sphere positioned a few units in front of the camera. I cannot seem to figure out how I have to translate the sphere correctly so that it is always aligned with the direction vector of the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an offset vector to the position in the direction the camera is looking:

```
sphere->TranslateModel(cameraPositionWorldSpace+camera->LookingDirection().normalized()*5);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I feel kind of stupid asking another question, but I simply cannot figure out how to calculate the `LookingDirection` of the camera. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722370/calculate-view-direction-from-rotation-angles